# How can I use this component in a single component in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am beginner of Vue.js.
I am trying to use a plugin called vue-base64-file-upload in a single component in VueCLI. However, it doesn't work in index.vue...

I have just changed the example (https://github.com/dhhb/vue-base64-file-upload) to this.

```
        <template>
           <div class="container">
           <h2>Upload file</h2>
           <vue-base64-file-upload 
           class="v1"
           accept="image/png,image/jpeg"
           image-class="v1-image"
           input-class="v1-input"
           :max-size="customImageMaxSize"
           @size-exceeded="onSizeExceeded"
           @file="onFile"
           @load="onLoad" />
           </div>
        </template>

        <script>
        import VueBase64FileUpload from 'vue-base64-file-upload';

        export default {
           data () {
                 return {
                    customImageMaxSize: 3 // megabytes
               };
            },
           components: {
               VueBase64FileUpload
             },
           methods: {
              onFile(file) {
              console.log(file); // file object
              },

              onLoad(dataUri) {
              console.log(dataUri); // data-uri string
              },

              onSizeExceeded(size) {
              alert(`Image ${size}Mb size exceeds limits of 
              ${this.customImageMaxSize}Mb!`);
              }
           },
        };
        app.$mount('#app');
```

Comment: `app.$mount('#app');` I do not see an app id element there. everything else looks good.

Comment: Are you wondering what to do inside of `onFile()` method ? Because the question `how can I use component X` is most probably answered in the X's documentation.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Please provide a minimal runnable example.